# How to use p:dataExporter without p:dataTable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to use dataExporter inside a p:commandButton without using p:dataTable. Is it possible..?

I am using Mozarra 2.0.3, Prime faces 2.2 RC2, Glass Fish 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  DataExporter only works with datatable.  You will need to write your own for other components.